# Is the std::map default constructor explicit?

Tags: c++, clang++, libc++

The following code compiles fine on g++ (various versions) but fails on clang++-3.4 with libc++ on my system:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::map<std::string, std::string> f() {
    return {};
}

int main() {
    auto m = f();
}
```

clang marks the following problem:

```
x.cpp:6:12: error: chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization
    return {};
           ^~
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm34/3.4.2/lib/llvm-3.4/bin/../include/c++/v1/map:838:14: note: constructor declared here
    explicit map(const key_compare& __comp = key_compare())
             ^
```

Indeed, the include file declares the constructor as `explicit`. <del>But it’s not marked as such in my C++11 draft standard.</del> Is this a bug in clang++/libc++? I was unable to find a relevant bug report.

Comment: It looks like it is `explicit` after all (at least, until C++14): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map

Comment: In the current working draft [n4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf#subsubsection.26.4.4.1) it is also marked `explicit`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph In your example and the error message, you are not invoking the copy constructor, the problem comes before that - when you are trying to default construct a `std::map`.

Comment: @Thomas I’m blind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no empty constructor before C++14. Default construction for `std::map<Key, Value, Compare, Allocator>` is marked `explicit` with 2 default parameters until C++14:

```
explicit map( const Compare& comp = Compare(), 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

After C++14, we have a non-`explicit` empty default constructor which calls the `explicit` constructor from before (which now does not have a default `Compare` argument):

```
map() : map( Compare() ) {}
explicit map( const Compare& comp, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

So your example would only be valid after C++14.

Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense. So g++ 4.8 (with `-std=c++1`) was wrong to accept it, correct?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, GCC should have rejected this when compiling with a C++11 compliant standard library.

Comment: Fair enough, but isn't a constructor whose parameters are all defaulted technically the default constructor – assuming there is no "real" default c'tor?

Comment: BTW, note how the `comp` parameter is no longer defaulted in C++14, probably to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: "A default constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` for which each parameter that is not a function parameter pack has a default argument (including the case of a constructor with no parameters)."